# Почему этот код выдаёт ошибки, но если поменять инклюды местами, то всё заработает?

Tags: c++, g++

Почему этот код выдаёт ошибки, но если поменять инклюды местами, то всё заработает?

```
#include "../../fio/fio/fio.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Ошибки:

```
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:5:19: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
 #define min(x,y) ({ \
               ^
 /home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:5:19: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘{’ token
 /home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:6:2: error: expected primary-expression before ‘typeof’
 typeof(x) _x = (x); \
 ^
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:6:2: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘typeof’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:195:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
 min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
 ^
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:195:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:8:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘void’
(void) (&_x == &_y);  \
^
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:8:3: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘void’
 /home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:9:2: error: ‘_x’ does not name a type
_x < _y ? _x : _y; })
^
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:9:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
_x < _y ? _x : _y; })
                  ^
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:13:19: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
 #define max(x,y) ({ \
               ^
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:13:19: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘{’ token
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:14:2: error: expected primary-expression before ‘typeof’
typeof(x) _x = (x); \
^
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:14:2: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘typeof’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:219:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
 max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
 ^
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:219:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:16:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘void’
(void) (&_x == &_y);  \
^
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:16:3: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘void’
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:17:2: error: ‘_x’ does not name a type
_x > _y ? _x : _y; })
^
/home/user/CLionProjects/1/../../fio/fio/minmax.h:17:21: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
_x > _y ? _x : _y; })
```

Компилирую с флагом -fpermissive

Comment: Вот здесь min(x,y) ({ круглая скобка перед фигурной ...({... явно лишняя

Comment: Это самое начало списка ошибок?

Comment: А зачем вы так располагаете включение заголовочных файлов? Как бы неписанное правило — от общего к частному.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что в одном из заголовочных файлов группы `fio` вы (или их авторы, если это кто-то другой) умудрились определить макро `min` и `max`, совпадающее по именам со стандартными функциями `std::min` и `std::max`. Эти макро в результате разносят вдребезги все стандартные объявления для стандартных `min` и `max`, а также попытки использовать стандартные `min` и `max` внутри стандартного заголовка `<iostream>` и/или во включаемых из него заголовках.

Comment: Задумка включения заголовочных файлов *от общего к частному*.